# how to copy file from my localhost to running container?

Tags: docker

I have started a container from our local docker registry. I don't have login access to our docker registry or docker host. I need to copy files from my localhost or laptop to running container.

Comment: Doesn't the container have a shared folder? You could use that to get the file into the container.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
docker cp /host/path/target <containerId>:/file/path/within/container
```

and in opposite way

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```